# Git cloning a Heroku app -- app out of date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I'm seeing an issue with cloning a Rails app, deployed on Heroku. I'm taking over from the old developer, so I'm still getting the lay of the land, as far as the design decisions made.

The issue that I'm seeing is that the cloned version of the app, that I'm able to download, is out of date with production. When I bash into the Heroku instance, I can tell it is the most recent code that is being ran, but when I clone the app, it is a month behind.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with regard to what may be causing this?

Comment: are you sure that you looking in correct branch, by default you clone `master` branch, but maybe to production was deployed another branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, [cloning from Heroku should be a last resort](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical "origin" repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub.

Now, on to the problem at hand. It's very likely that the previous developer was deploying via GitHub or some other means, not via `git push`:

> You **cannot** clone your app's source from Heroku if you deploy your app with any method besides `git push`. Other deployment methods do not update your app’s Heroku Git repo, causing `heroku git:clone` to return an empty repository. These other deployment methods include:
>
> - [Deploying directly from GitHub](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/github-integration)
> - [Heroku Container Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime)
> - [The Heroku Button](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-button)

Ideally, you should really get a recent copy of the source code from the previous developer.

This depends on the laws in effect wherever you are, whatever contract might have existed, etc., but your client probably owns the source code the previous developer wrote. Even if this isn't *legally* true (in many jurisdictions it is), I'd argue that it's *ethically* true. A good strategy is for your client to own the repository where the source code lives.

But that doesn't help now.

I've never done this, but you could try [to retrieve the application slug](https://help.heroku.com/FZDDCBLB/how-can-i-download-my-code-from-heroku) from the currently deployed application:

> If you have not used git to deploy your application, or using heroku `git:clone` has only created an empty repository, you can download the slug that was build when you application was last deployed. First, install the [heroku-slugs](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-slugs) CLI plugin with `heroku plugins:install heroku-slugs`, then run:
>
> ```
> heroku slugs:download -a APP_NAME
> ```
>
> This will download and compress your slug into a directory with the same name as your application.

You could then manually merge the slug contents into your existing Git repository and make a big commit with a message like "Update entire application from Heroku slug".

Answer (score 1):

You should go on your Heroku dashboard in the Activity tab, there you will see what version was last deployed, giving you the commit hash:

[image]

With this information you can easily track what commit was deployed and compare it with what you have on Github.

It's unlikely but possible that the last deployed version on Heroku was never pushed on Github, you can find out easily once you have the deployed commit hash.

Comment: The plot thickens. There are no other alternate branches other than master for this app. I also don't have access to the Github the previous developer was using. Additionally, this particular app has been put into a Heroku pipeline with staging and production stages. Would the fact that this app is part of a pipeline affect heroku git:clone?